# Autowiring ApplicationListener as null

Tags: java, spring, null, javabeans

Dear StackOverflow experts.

We are solving interesting issue in current sprint and our understanding of Spring workflow doesn't allow us to find a solution.
So we ask you to share your thought on next problem:

We need to import class from a library which we can not modify right now.
The thing is that the class we need to import has an Autowired dependency of a class which implements "ApplicationListener".
We won't use this dependency in our code (it is used in methods we won't call).

We trying to set all unused dependencies to null.
But when we set this class to null we get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delegate listener must not be null
```

Obviously, we don't want to instantiate ApplicationListener class in our application.

To reproduce our situation we create a simple unit tests:

Application configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> applicationListener() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ConfigurationManagerTests extends      AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> applicationListener;

    @Test
    public void dummyTest() {
        Assert.assertNull(applicationListener);
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace of the exception listed below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delegate listener must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.<init>(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:229)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 33 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Spring itself doesn't allow that bean to be null, so why not just create a dummy one which doesn't do anything?

```
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> applicationListener() {
  return new ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
      // Do nothing
    }   
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! Implemented the ApplicationListener to do nothing on ContentRefreshedEvents.